# Rewrite .htaccess with multiple parameter

Tags: .htaccess

i want rewrite `/q.php?start=0&co=US&l=AL&s=hotel` to `/us/al/hotel`

I tried this, but I get error - nothing found. and this my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /q.php?start=0&co=$1&l=$2&s=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Where is this .htaccess located? Are there more rules?

Comment: this located in public_html

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Do you think you answered my question completely?

Comment: still can not rewrite

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /q.php?start=0&co=$1&l=$2&s=$3 [L]
```